# Jenkinsfile - get parent path in environment block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to get the parent directory of the current WORKSPACE and set the value to the environment variable.
I tried the following:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'test'
    }
    
    environment{
        COMMON = "${Paths.get(env.WORKSPACE).getParent()}"
    }
    
    stages { ... }
```

But when I run it I get the following exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more variables have some issues with their values: COMMON`.

I have a solution as a last resort -> run `powershell/bash` script as the first stage and calculate the path there. But in this case, the step will be displayed on UI, which is undesired.
Any thoughts about how to calculate the parent directory value directly in the environment block?

Comment: You should probably use the `env` map instead of the `environment` block.

Comment: the WORKSPACE is by default set as an environment variable in Jenkins I believe... In my build environment, I've the values populated by default and I use `${WORKSPACE}` variable in my pipeline code. check https://your-build-url/env-vars.html to see if that is already available first.

Comment: @vijay Yes, WORKSPACE is set properly in my case and my question isn't about workspace itself, but is about the way how to get the path to its parent directory

Comment: @MattSchuchard Not sure if I understand how it could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Af far as I know and as you stated yourself, the only way to set an environment variable dynamically is by using bat/sh/powershell (see [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables-dynamically)). To assign the return value to a variable you want to use returnStdout which will suppress output in the console log.
e.g.
`COMMON = bat(script:"dir", returnStdout: true)`